# libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd() in LibVLC.NET

Tags: c#, vlc, gtk#, libvlc

I need to use libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd() function in GTK#, but I can't find it. Instead of this I found this function in [LibVLC.NET](http://libvlcnet.codeplex.com):

```
//==========================================================================
// void libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks (libvlc_media_player_t *mp, libvlc_video_format_cb setup, libvlc_video_cleanup_cb cleanup)

//==========================================================================
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate uint libvlc_video_format_cb(ref IntPtr opaque, ref uint chroma, ref uint width, ref uint height, ref uint pitches, ref uint lines);

//==========================================================================
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void libvlc_video_cleanup_cb(IntPtr opaque);

//==========================================================================
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks_signature(IntPtr mp, libvlc_video_format_cb setup, libvlc_video_cleanup_cb cleanup);

//==========================================================================
private readonly libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks_signature m_libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks;

//==========================================================================
public void libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks(IntPtr mp, libvlc_video_format_cb setup, libvlc_video_cleanup_cb cleanup)
{
  VerifyAccess();

  m_libvlc_video_set_format_callbacks(mp, setup, cleanup);
}

/*
  void libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, void *drawable)
  void * libvlc_media_player_get_nsobject (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
  void libvlc_media_player_set_agl (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, uint32_t drawable)
  uint32_t libvlc_media_player_get_agl (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
  void libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, uint32_t drawable)
  uint32_t libvlc_media_player_get_xwindow (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
  void libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi, void *drawable)
  void * libvlc_media_player_get_hwnd (libvlc_media_player_t *p_mi)
*/
```

In the comments there is mention of libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (), may be this function somehow replace it or give access to the same opportunities as libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd ()?

So I need this function or function which replaces it, or method that will help me play video in the needed window or gtk.widget(may be I need to get bitmap of an image or something like this).

What can i do?

Answer (score 2):

`libvlc`/`video`/`set_format_callbacks` is meant completely for different things than `libvlc`/`media_player`/`set_hwnd`. While the use of the latter is fairly obvious (selecting target screen area), the former (according to [this source](http://projectsymphony.blogspot.com/2013/04/finally-one-libvlcvideosetformatcallbac.html)) is a callback replacement for `libvlc_video_set_format`. Well, I didn't check the libvlc docs, but it's probably described well there. I'm no expert in libvlc, but, IMHO, these two functions are far from each other.

Regarding other functions that were visible in comments in the code:

- libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject -- uses NSView (Cocoa)
- libvlc_media_player_get_nsobject -- returns NSView (Cocoa) previously set by the former
- libvlc_media_player_set_agl -- likewise, but for AGL (Apple OpenGL)
- libvlc_media_player_get_agl -- likewise, but for AGL (Apple OpenGL)
- libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow -- likewise, but for XWindows (genric Linux+XWin)
- libvlc_media_player_get_xwindow -- likewise, but for XWindows (genric Linux+XWin)
- libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd -- likewise, but for Microsoft Windows
- libvlc_media_player_get_hwnd -- likewise, but for Microsoft Windows

(see [the docs about them](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html))

So, it depends on **what platform** you are trying to use the libVlc, because that dictates the way the VLC can draw upon the screen.

If you are building for whatever on MS Windows - use HWND pair.
If you are building for Linux with XWindows - use XWindow pair.
If you are building for Cocoa on MacOS/iOS - use NSObject/NSView pair.
If you are building for OpenGL on MaxOS/iOS - use AGL pair.

On MS Windows, you must use HWND. Even if you are using WPF/GTK#/whatever. Every window in MS Windows uses HWND at its root. Dig it out from your UI library. It is somewhere there. But it might be unsatisfactory. For example, WPF (unless you do some tricks) uses exactly one HWND handle for each Window object. Passing this HWND to VLC would result in VLC drawing all other the window, not just the region you would want. That must be solved by different means, for example - creating another smaller window, keeping it on top ofthe main one, and constantly syncing its position so it moves as if it were glued to the main one. Ugly, but simple and works in most cases.